# Deploy published mvc application as Azure Web App programatically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, msbuild, azure-web-app-service, msdeploy

I have published my MVC application and now I want to deploy the same as Azure Web App.

I want my customers to open a .bat file in which they will be prompted for Azure Publish Settings and deploy the application.

I dont want to do the below.

- Deploy the solution directly from Visual Studio
- Use MsDeploy or MSBuild to build the solution with publish profiles like the below and publish in Azure
  `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe "I:\MyProject\MyProject.sln" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=Production /p:Password=Mu50vKJfDdKfGsFvj5erC0awdxAi /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true  /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0`

Can anyone suggest a solution ?

Thanks,
R. Venkatesan

Answer (score 1):

There are several tools you can use to deploy a web app from the command line :

- Azure CLI : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-deploy/#cli
- Web Deploy Command Line : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-deploy/#webdeploy

I would prefer use a custom script that use Azure CLI so your customer will be asked for login to Azure instead of providing publish settings file.

Hope this helps,

Julien